# Delphi component's programming

Tags: delphi, user-interface, components

Does anybody know if it is possible to visually see and edit components at developing time? i would like to create a component based on TPanel, but i dont have any design window (or dfm) where i can visually add components on it, i found related threads in which some programmers claim its not possible.

Any ideas if its possible and how?

thnx

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do here. Are you creating a custom component that inherits from TPanel that also contains other controls TEdit, TLabels perhaps?

Comment: @LachlanG: sorry for the confusion, its as you mentioned for example a Panel with checkbox and editbox on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope. Using frames is the best you can do to develop compound components with the aid of the visual designers.

See this article http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+II+Delphi+Object-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+9+Writing+Delphi+Components/Creating+Compound+Components/

And specifically the section "Building Compound Components with Frames".

Comment: +1 for a clear answer and very informative articel, i have to admit beeing a bit disappointed as i was sure it would be possible to visually design the component using a Panel during development. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Make a project group.
Add a package to that project group.
Add/install a component in that package.
Add a VCL forms application to the project group.
Right click on a project group and choose build all.
This way you will be able to 'visually' track the progress of your component during the development.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to compound components is to use [component templates](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_Component_Templates).

They're not proper components, rather they're just a shortcut to you copying and pasting the components and their event handlers from one form to another. You can manipulate them using the designer though so they may be suitable for your purposes.

Comment: That's something I didn't know. I had never even wondered what that menu item did. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

what you are asking is, I believe, is how to create components and interact with them at design time no ?(by example the behavior of datasets, properties of a form,etc).

here you have an example 
http://www.podgoretsky.com/ftp/docs/Delphi/D5/dg/register.html

best regards, 
Radu

Comment: @Rabu: Thnx for the Link, i meant to visually c the component while i develope it so i dont have for example to position each internal component i put on it by code, sorry for any confusion caused by unclear description.

Answer (score 0):

I take this question to mean that you wish to develop a custom component and to do so visually rather than in code. If that is your question then I'm afraid that you can't do it.

Comment: Hi David, i meant to visually design the component and programm the behaviour's code.

Comment: That's what I understood your question to be. You can't do it.